# Pushing array into multidimensional array (php)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've attempted many different ways to push an array into a multidimensional array, including `array_push()`, `$array['index'] = $toPush` but I keep being met with quite unexpected results. I have used both `var_dump()` and `print_r()` as detailed below in an attempt to debug, but cannot work out the issue.

My reasoning behind is to run a while loop to pull game id's and game names and store these in an assoc. array, and then push them into my main array.

```
$games_array = array 
(

    "games" => array 
     (
          array("id"=>"1", "game"=>"first game");
          array("id"=>"2", "game"=>"second game");
     )

);
// a while loop would run here and update $game_to_add;
$game_to_add = array("id"=>"$game['id']", "game"=>"$game['title']");

$games_array = array_push($games_array['games'], $game_to_add);
```

In this example, the `while()` would update the ID and the Game inside of `$game_to_add`

But, whenever I attempt this it simply overwrites the array and outputs an integer ( example: `int(3)` )

I don't understand what the problem is, any explination would be appreciated as I cannot find a question specifically for this.

My actual test code:

```
$games_array = array( "games" => array(
    array("id" => "1", "name" => "Star feathers"),
    array("id" => "2", "name" => "chung fu")
)
);

$another_game = array("id" => "3", "name" => "some kunt");
$games_array = array_push($games_array["games"], array("id" => "3", "name" 
=>"some game"));
var_dump($games_array);
```

Comment: Get rid of the `$games_array` assignment before `array_push()`. It modifies the array in place, it doesn't return it.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that. I used `Array_push()` all over the shop, guess I was too close to the woods to see the trees.

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you get out of the habit of using `array_push`, and use the shorthand `$arrayname[] = $new_value;`

Comment: e.g. `$games_array["games"][] = $another_game;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning the return value of array_push to the "games" array.
The return value of `array_push` is the amount of elements after pushing.

Just use it as

```
array_push($array, $newElement);
```

(Without assignment)

If you're only pushing one element at the time, `$array[] = $newElement` is preferred to the prevent overhead of the function call of `array_push`